# I cannot view components of an array

Tags: arrays, opencv, struct, components

I'm using the following openCV variables:

```
std::vector<cv::DMatch> best_matches;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> tkeypoints[15];
```

When I press the "." and try to get the components of best_matches, for example best_matches[i].queryIdx then queryIdx appears correctly in the suggestion list.

However, when I try to get the components of tkeypoints, for example tkeypoints[i].angle, I don't see that on the suggestion list and I get an error if I try to run it like that.

Why I can't access the components in the second array?

[image: tkeypoints]
*tkeypoints*

[image: best_matches]
*best_matches*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since is

```
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> tkeypoints[15];
```

you should access it like:

```
tkeypoints[i][j].angle
```